# Jupyter Lab Max Number of Outputs Trimmed

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

How to change Jupyter Lab default behaviour trimming higher number of outputs.
The message in the middle of outputs says:

```
Output of this cell has been trimmed on the initial display. 
Displaying the first 50 top and last bottom outputs. 
Click on this message to get the complete output.
```

There is `maxNumberOutputs` parameter in Jupyter Lab [source code](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/master/packages/outputarea/src/widget.ts), but I didn't found any method to change it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can change `maxNumberOutputs` in settings: click on  Menu bar → `Settings` → `Advanced Settings Editor` → `Notebook` → set `maxNumberOutputs` in the `User Preferences` tab, like:

```json
{
    "maxNumberOutputs": 100
}
```

save, and reload.

Comment: Is there a way to change this setting for a single cell directly from the notebook?

Comment: on my version (jupyter lab 3.3.4 ) clicking "Advanced Settings Editor" in the menu opened just some sort of 'standard' Settings tab. To see advanced (i.e. to be able to add in the {..} section I had to click on 'JSON Settings editor' in top right corner

Answer (score 1):

Using `jupyter lab path` to find the "User settings" path, you can write from the notebook directly by executing this writefile magic from within a cell:

```
%%writefile <your-jupyter-lab-path>/user-settings/@jupyterlab/notebook-extension/tracker.jupyterlab-settings
{
    "maxNumberOutputs":100
}
```

This path may be slightly different depending on your environment and Jupyterlab version, so probably best to manually change it using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69619766/1673784) and then finding the file that was modified. After that you can place this code before the `%%writefile` command to ensure that this works on your next Jupyter session without manually going to advanced settings in the menu bar:

```
!file="<your-jupyter-lab-path>/user-settings/@jupyterlab/notebook-extension/tracker.jupyterlab-settings" && mkdir -p "${file%/*}" && touch "$file"
```

Finally, to ensure that you have correctly changed the values,use this code to test your output:

```
from IPython.display import display
[display(i) for i in range(75)]
```

where 75 outputs should not be trimmed. If it is, then try refreshing the page to re-apply the settings.